# keypressed event not being called

Tags: java, swing, awt

```
public GuiC() {
    getContentPane().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("hi");

        }
    });
    setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    setTitle("Hi!");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

}
```

so this is my frame did i do something wrong here?because the keyevent isnt being called when i press any key please help :)

Comment: Avoid using `KeyListener` and rather use Swing Keybindings (just google "Swing Key bindings" for more info). It will save you tremendous amount of time. Also, you should really avoid `null`-layout such as this: `getContentPane().setLayout(null);`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to request focus.

```
public GuiC() {
    this.getContentPane().requestFocus(); //request focus here
    this.getContentPane().addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("hi: " + e.getKeyChar());

    }
});
    setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    setTitle("Hi!");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

}
```

Additional reading: [How to Write a Key Listener](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: Kudos for citing the tutorial, but shouldn't you follow its advice on requesting focus?

Answer (score 0):

Your code as such is fine. 
I usually use a `KeyListener`

```
getContentPane().addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("hi");
```

See here for a tutorial:

http://java.about.com/od/Handling-Events/ss/A-Keylistener-Example-Program.htm
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

I personally dislike the anonymous class solution.

The Oracle way of doing it is much cleaner.

```
//make your class implement KeyListener
public class KeyEventDemo ...  implements KeyListener ... {  

//use `this` as the listener
typingArea.addKeyListener(this);  <<-- simple

//Add the relevant listeners to the class
/** Handle the key-pressed event from the text field. */
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    displayInfo(e, "KEY PRESSED: ");
}

/** Handle the key-released event from the text field. */
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    displayInfo(e, "KEY RELEASED: ");
}
```

Comment: Ah, didn't spot that it wasn't a KeyListener. I updated my answer to include this.